# trouble implementing Interface

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2017

I want to execute the `ShowControls()` method in Class2 (and other) classes by using an interface.  Show Controls() method contains a switch statment that determines to show or hide various controls (many of which are custom user controls) in GridView's item template based on it's row index during GridView databind. When I call the method from Class2 I am getting this error message: *CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.EventArgs' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs'*. This confuses me since I clearly have specified parameter `GridViewRowEventArgs` in the method.

Can someone help me set this up correctly?  Maybe I can't reference web controls in an Interface?  I have referenced specifically the following using statements in  `I_BuildGridView` and `BuildControl`:

```
using System.Web; 
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

Here's how I have the Interface set up:

```
public interface I_BuildGridView
    {
        void ShowControls(GridViewRowEventArgs e);

    }

public class BuildControls: I_BuildGridView 
    {
      public void ShowControls(GridViewRowEventArgs e)
      {//switch statement here -it's very long so left out here…}
    }  

public partial class Class2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {     
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            { 
                 //Call interface here
                 I_BuildGridView oShow = new BuildControls();
                oShow.ShowControls(e);//<--error here CS1503 red sqiggly under the e
            }
```

FYI: I used [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18743/Interfaces-in-C-For-Beginners) reference to build the Interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about it I realized that the Page_Load() event wasn't the place to call the ShowControls() method but the GridViews' RowDataBound event was - because the reference to the parameter would be available from there and not known yet in the Page_Load() event.